# Encode URL contains special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, special-characters, encode, nsurl

I have a URL that contains special characters (% is used very much).. i want to encode the URL,how?
this is one example of my my URLs: http://some.com//en/it/name-50%-other-set-50%-/68

I tried the following :

```
//  Option - 1.

NSString* str = [self.shareURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//  Option - 2. 

NSString *unsafeString = @"this &string= confuses ? the InTeRwEbZ";
CFStringRef safeString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes (
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unsafeString,
    NULL,
    CFSTR("/%&=?$#+-~@<>|\\*,.()[]{}^!"),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8
);

//  Option - 3.

NSString *escapedString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you said, http://some.com//en/it/name-50%-other-set-50%-/68 is a bad URL. What is the good URL you're supposed to have ?

And why is there // after .com?

Comment: Yes ..you are right , i dont know how i didnt figure this before,thanx

Answer (score 0):

Tackling your three variations in order:

1. Using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is convenient and would solve your problem of a URL with a `%` in it.

   However, this method is quite limited and doesn't solve many common percent escaping problems. What if, for example, your curious URL path string had a `?` in it? This method would let that question mark go unescaped (because a question mark is valid in URLs as a way of delimiting the start of request parameters), which would be a problem in this case if you really needed the `?` as part of that path.

   In practice, while people love to suggest `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` as the response to percent escaping questions, it invariably doesn't provide enough control to do the job adequately.
2. This leads us to `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, which is the Core Foundation function that provides a greater level of control. Prior to iOS 7, this was the "go to" solution, allowing you to qualify which "legal characters" you might want to additionally escape (e.g., `?` in my prior example). You can also specify what characters that are generally escaped that you might want to leave unescaped.

   Three observations on your example of this function, though:

   - You have specified a large set of characters to be escaped, including a few that would have been escaped anyway. It doesn't hurt to include these extra characters, but suggests a slight misunderstanding about what this function does.
   - Likewise, you're escaping some characters (`.`, `-`, and `~`) that don't need escaping.
   - Finally, when we use this function in our Objective-C code, we generally will return it as a `NSString` and transfer ownership with `CFBridgingRelease` or `__bridge_transfer`. This saves us from having to deal with Core Foundation types and having to manually `CFRelease`.

   Anyway, this yields something like:

   ```
   - (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
   {
       return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                        (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                        NULL,
                                                                        (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
   }
   ```

   By the way, if you do this sort of percent escape routine, do it on the individual components of the URL (e.g. just that portion of the path with the "50%" in the name), not the whole URL. There are characters that are valid in the URL (e.g., `/` or `:`), but wouldn't be valid in this path, so you want to percent escape those characters in the path, but not the URL as a whole.
3. This leads us to `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`. This method, introduced in iOS 7, provides the same level of control the above Core Foundation function does, but without the hassles of bridging. Just pick the appropriate character set, and it will go from there.